# Angular 6 not showing HTML parse errors

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I'm not sure when this started happening, possibly after I updated some packages, but I no longer get any error messages for errors in my HTML, in the console nor in the terminal.
Node compiles and then stops at the default **Loading...** index page.

This happens when I have an error in my HTML, for example not a properly closed tag:

```
<div>Some div<div>
```

If it's only on one page I can find the problem, but if I have a ton of HTML there's no easy way to find where the issue is coming from.

Is anyone else having this same problem, is there a fix for it?

Comment: Are there no errors in the console?

Comment: did you try a ng build --prod? (assuming you have angular-cli)

Comment: Angular has a highly opinionated and at times a somewhat annoying template validation process. I am surprised to hear that you're not getting any errors especially with something so blatant as missing closing tags. Angular shouldn't even build successfully if you have such invalid HTML. Could you provide a [mcve] or more specific information/code in general?

Comment: Thanks @maerlin! I forgot about `ng build`, it gave me error messages I could use. ```ERROR in : Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "section". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
        </div>

[ERROR ->]</section>
")```

Comment: @Narm I'll see if I can make a reproducible example, but I suspect the cause is from some combination of node and angular or angular-cli versions

Comment: @Niels, nice to hear. I think you would have had the errors in runtime, but with the prod build and AOT, the templates are getting compiled during the build process, thats why the prod build detects every single invalid tag.